# IOError using shutil.copyfile() on Windows

Tags: python, windows, shutil

I've tried making my first Python program which will copy all files from one folder and paste them into another:

```
import shutil
shutil.copyfile("C:\Users\USER\Desktop\MoveFrom\Test.txt",
                "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\MoveTo")
```

But I keep getting an error message and can't figure out why:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Python\movefiles.py", line 2, in <module>
    shutil.copyfile("C:\Users\USER\Desktop\MoveFrom\Test.txt", "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\MoveTo")
  File "C:\PYTHON27\lib\shutil.py", line 83, in copyfile
    with open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\USER\\Desktop\\MoveTo'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `shutil.copyfile()`, you need to give the full destination path, (including new filename), not just the destination directory like you might do with the `copy` command.

Also, note that in most all languages, backslashes are interpreted specially inside of string literals by the language. So the paths you were using were completely invalid. You need to either *escape* the backslashes (by adding another backslash in front of each one) in your paths, or use the `r` prefix, which tells Python not to interpret backslashes specially.

```
import shutil
shutil.copyfile(
    r"C:\Users\USER\Desktop\MoveFrom\Test.txt",
    r"C:\Users\USER\Desktop\MoveTo\Test.txt")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need `copy()` instead of `copyfile()`, see https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html.

> Copy the contents (no metadata) of the file named src to a file named dst. dst must be the complete target file name; look at shutil.copy() for a copy that accepts a target directory path.